# overlap of div over another section of the body when trying to insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hava a chart : [code for chart](https://jsfiddle.net/qp7L1hob/)

I am trying to put this chart within a website.[website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/)

Problem is that one div overflows the other as can be seen in the website.
I tried changing the position of the chart to relative from absolute.It doesnot work.

What may be the issue.Why is this happening ?Any idea.

fiddle related to the website :[My code so far](https://jsfiddle.net/jn1ba77s/) (experiment here)

My Code for the website( everything is available in above fiddle link) :

```js
'use strict';

var dataset = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

// let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'];
let colors = ['#67001f', '#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#e0e0e0', '#bababa', '#878787', '#4d4d4d', '#1a1a1a', 'white', 'white'];
var months = ['January - 2016', 'February - 2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];
var dataWeeks = ["Week 1: 32<br>Week 2: 54<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 12", "Week 5: 22<br>Week 6: 14<br>Week 7: 12<br>Week 8: 03<br>Week 9:44", "Week 10: 14<br>Week 11: 11<br>Week 12: 23<br>Week 13:20 <br>Quarter 1 :25", "Week 14: 53<br>Week 15: 16<br>Week 16: 11 <br>Week 17:33", "Week 18: 52<br>Week 19: 22<br>Week 20: 12 <br>Week 21 :09 <br>Week 22:34", "Week 23: 59<br>Week 24: 87 <br>Week 25:36<br>Week 26:78<br>Quarter 2 :56<br>Half Yearly 1 :98", "Week 27: 69<br>Week 28: 33<br>Week 29: 11<br>Week 30: 65", "Week 31: 69<br>Week 32: 33<br>Week 33: 99<br>Week 34: 66<br>Week 35: 19", "Week 36: 84<br>Week 37: 16<br>Week 38: 66<br>Week 39: 11<br>Quarter 3 : 77", "Week 40: 86<br>Week 41: 21<br>Week 42: 52<br>Week 43: 12<br>Week 44: 37", "Week 45: 90<br>Week 46: 69<br>Week 47: 19<br>Week 48: 17", "Week 49:33 <br>Week 50:09 <br>Week 51:44 <br>Week 52 : 89<br>Quarter 4 :66<br>Half Yearly 2:99"];

var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
  height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
  minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  initialAnimDelay = 300,
  arcAnimDelay = 150,
  arcAnimDur = 3000,
  secDur = 1000,
  secIndividualdelay = 150;

var radius = undefined;

// calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
if (minOfWH > 200) {
  radius = 200;
} else {
  radius = minOfWH;
}

// append svg
var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
  'width': width,
  'height': height,
  'class': 'pieChart'
}).append('g');

svg.attr({
  'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
});

// for drawing slices
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

// for labels and polylines
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

// d3 color generator
// let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d;
});

var draw = function draw() {

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

  // define slice
  var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(dataset).selectAll('path').data(pie);
  slice.enter().append('path').attr({
    'fill': function fill(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    },
    'd': arc,
    'stroke-width': '25px'
  }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
  }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
  }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

  slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

  var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  };

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(dataset));

  text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).text(function(d, i) {
    return months[i];
  }).attr('transform', function(d) {
    // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    // define left and right alignment of text labels
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
  }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);

  text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.html(dataWeeks[i])
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 14 + 'px')
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  });


  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(dataset));

  polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
  }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
  });
};

draw();

var button = document.querySelector('button');

var replay = function replay() {

  d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

  setTimeout(draw, 800);
};
```

```css
.fl-lt {
  float: left;
}
.fl-rt {
  float: right;
}
/* Clear Floated Elements
---------------------------------*/

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.figure {
  margin: 0px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:active {
  outline: 0px !important
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* Primary Styles
---------------------------------*/

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #888888;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #222222;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #888888;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Navigation
---------------------------------*/

.main-nav-outer {
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px -3px #ececec;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.main-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
.main-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222222;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 17px 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.main-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7cc576;
}
.small-logo {
  padding: 0 32px;
}
/* Clients
---------------------------------*/

.client-part {
  background: url(../img/section-bg1.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 55px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.client-part-haead {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 41px;
  margin: 30px 0 10px;
  font-family: ''Open Sans',sans-serif';
  font-style: italic;
}
.client {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.client li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 15px;
}
.client li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.client li a img {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.client li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.client li a h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.client li a span {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.quote-right {
  font-style: normal;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #7cc576;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 68px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #7cc576;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.quote-right:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.c-logo-part {
  background: #7cc576;
  padding: 25px 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
.c-logo-part ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.c-logo-part ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 25px;
}
.c-logo-part ul a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
/* Talk Business
---------------------------------*/

.business-talking {
  background: url(../img/section-bg2.jpg) top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 60px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.business-talking h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Contact
---------------------------------*/

.main-section.contact {
  padding: 90px 0 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.main-section.contact {
  background: url(../img/bg-map.png) left 190px no-repeat;
}
.contact-info-box {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 14px 68px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.contact-info-box h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  float: left;
  width: 102px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.contact-info-box h3 i {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #222222;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
.contact-info-box span {
  line-height: 28px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.social-link {
  padding: 35px 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 68px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
}
.social-link li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.social-link li a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #222222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.social-link li a:hover,
.social-link li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.twitter a:hover {
  background: #55acee;
}
.facebook a:hover {
  background: #3b5998;
}
.pinterest a:hover {
  background: #cb2026;
}
.gplus a:hover {
  background: #dd4b39;
}
.dribbble a:hover {
  background: #ea4c89;
}
.form {
  margin: 0 66px 0 30px;
}
.input-text {
  padding: 15px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #aaa;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.input-text:focus {
  border: 1px solid #7cc576;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(124, 197, 118, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(124, 197, 118, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(124, 197, 118, 0.3);
}
.input-text.text-area {
  height: 165px;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
.input-btn {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #7cc576;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.input-btn:hover {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
}
.validation {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#sendmessage {
  color: #7cc576;
  border: 1px solid #7cc576;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#errormessage {
  color: red;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#sendmessage.show,
#errormessage.show,
.show {
  display: block;
}
/* chart related css
---------------------------------*/

   
.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  position: relative;
}
path {
  stroke: #0d0d0d;
  /* stroke-width: 5px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: fill 250ms;
  transition: fill 250ms;
}
path:hover {
  /* stroke-width: 10px; */
  fill: #fff;
}
text {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5px;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 820px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: .6em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

/*chart related css*/

.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  position: relative;
}
path {
  stroke: #0d0d0d;
  /* stroke-width: 5px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: fill 250ms;
  transition: fill 250ms;
}
path:hover {
  /* stroke-width: 10px; */
  fill: #fff;
}
text {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5px;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 820px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: .6em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Homepage</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="img/x-icon">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,800italic,700italic,600italic,400italic,300italic,800,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">.pie {behavior:url(PIE.htc);}</style><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/classie.js"></script>

<script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="main-nav-outer" id="test">
    <!--main-nav-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#header">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#service">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="small-logo">
          <a href="#header">
            <img src="img/small-logo.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#client">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#team">TeamChart</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="res-nav_click" href="#"><i class="fa-bars"></i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--main-nav-end-->

  <section class="main-section client-part" id="client">
    <!--main-section client-part-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <b class="quote-right wow fadeInDown delay-03"><i class="fa-quote-right"></i></b>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
         
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="client wow fadeIn delay-05s">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="img/client-pic1.jpg" alt="">
            <h3>James Bond</h3>
            <span>License To Drink Inc.</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--main-section client-part-end-->
  <div class="c-logo-part">
    <!--c-logo-part-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
   



  <!-- chart section -->



  <section class="main-section team" id="team">
    <!--main-section team-start-->

    <h2>TeamChart</h2>
    <h6>Chart talks about the points required</h6>
    <div class="chart-wrapper"></div>
    <button onclick='replay()'>Replay</button>
    <div class="textt" data-tip="this is the data ."></div>
  </section>
  <!--main-section team-end-->
  <section class="business-talking">
    <!--business-talking-start-->
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Let’s Talk Business.</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--business-talking-end-->
  <div class="container">
    <section class="main-section contact" id="contact">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-7 wow fadeInLeft">
          <div class="contact-info-box address clearfix">
            <h3><i class=" icon-map-marker"></i>Address:</h3>
            <span>308 Negra Arroyo Lane<br>Albuquerque, New Mexico, 87111.</span>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-info-box phone clearfix">
            <h3><i class="fa-phone"></i>Phone:</h3>
         <span>1-800-BOO-YAHH</span>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-info-box email clearfix">
            <h3><i class="fa-pencil"></i>email:</h3>
            <span>hello@knightstudios.com</span>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-info-box hours clearfix">
            <h3><i class="fa-clock-o"></i>Hours:</h3>
            <span><strong>Monday - Thursday:</strong> 10am - 6pm<br><strong>Friday:</strong> People work on Fridays now?<br><strong>Saturday - Sunday:</strong> Best not to ask.</span>
          </div>
          <ul class="social-link">
            <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="pinterest"><a href="#"><i class="fa-pinterest"></i</a>
            </li>
            <li class="gplus"><a href="#"><i class="fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa-dribbble"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 wow fadeInUp delay-05s">
          <div class="form">
           <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
            <div id="errormessage"></div>
            <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control input-text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control input-text text-area" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <div class="validation"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="input-btn">Send Message</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('#test').scrollToFixed();
      $('.res-nav_click').click(function() {
        $('.main-nav').slideToggle();
        return false

      });

    });
  </script>
  <script>
    wow = new WOW({
      animateClass: 'animated',
      offset: 100
    });
    wow.init();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {

      $('.main-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 102
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        /*
   if you don't want to use the easing effects:
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
   }, 1000);
   */
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    })
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      var $container = $('.portfolioContainer'),
        $body = $('body'),
        colW = 375,
        columns = null;
      $container.isotope({
        // disable window resizing
        resizable: true,
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: colW
        }
      });
      $(window).smartresize(function() {
        // check if columns has changed
        var currentColumns = Math.floor(($body.width() - 30) / colW);
        if (currentColumns !== columns) {
          // set new column count
          columns = currentColumns;
          // apply width to container manually, then trigger relayout
          $container.width(columns * colW)
            .isotope('reLayout');
        }
      }).smartresize(); // trigger resize to set container width
      $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function() {
        $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({

          filter: selector,
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
  </script>
  <script src="js/indexpiechart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you update your code in fiddle or codepen

Comment: The website fiddle,doesnot work.I will download the website from the zip and try to integrate the chart in it. In the meantime,plz try that the website fiddle work.It will save a lot of time for us. @Jane

Comment: Also good job with that chart

Comment: @Jisnhu Thanks for the input.I tried doing so.The code is not getting uploaded.So,i provided the link fr the website to download.Anyways,I will try to use codepen. Thanks.God bless

Comment: @ShivamSharma thanks.Yeah,u can check like that.

Comment: changing the position to relative looks fine for me

Comment: @phobia82 I have already tried that.So,thought to mention that in the question.I am thinking why this problem is happening as changing the position should solve the issue. Anyways,thanks for the input.God bless.

Comment: Can you provide an screenshot highlighting what looks wrong for you when using position:relative?